# Spring Boot: change the upload max size for a single endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

It is possible to define globally the maximum file size and request size in Spring Boot by using:

```
# Spring Boot v1
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

# Sprint Boot v2
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

But is it possible to override the global limit for a specific endpoint?

For instance, I want a default limit of 10MB but for a specific endpoint, I want to be able to upload files as big as 1GB.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge thats not possible. But you could define the default upload size as 1 GB and create a JavaScript function that validates the upload size of the files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).